# Using C++ with boost program options result in a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, boost, raspberry-pi3

I wrote a small app which was compiled on a Raspberry Pi2. The program used program option from boost. The Pi died, so I want to run the the app on a new Pi 3. The compiling/linking works without problems. Starting the application result in a segmentation fault.

Some parts of the code:

```
v_AppName = boost::filesystem::basename(argv[0]); 
po::options_description desc("Opties"); 
ProgramOptions(desc);
po::variables_map vm; 
try 
{ 
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
    ....
```

Program options function (the part which causes the problem):

```
void Client::ProgramOptions(boost::program_options::options_description & l_Desc)
{
    l_Desc.add_options()
    ("help,h", "Show help")
    ("view,v", "View something")
    ("TEST", po::value<int>(), "TEST");
}
```

The last line with po::value() in it causes the crash. If i remove this line the program runs.

Stacktrace:

```
#0  0x76f17f24 in 
  boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::parse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, bool) const () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_program_options.so.1.55.0
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x76f13220 in boost::program_options::store(boost::program_options::basic_parsed_options<char> const&, boost::program_options::variables_map&, bool) ()
   from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_program_options.so.1.55.0
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x0003cae0 in warmte::Client::Client (this=0x7efff618, argc=1, argv=0x7efff794) at src/client.cpp:38
    timeout = {<boost::date_time::base_time<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::date_time::counted_time_system<boost::date_time::counted_time_rep<boost::posix_time::millisec_posix_time_system_config> > >> = {<boost::operators_impl::less_than_comparable<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::operators_impl::equality_comparable<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::operators_impl::operators_detail::empty_base<boost::posix_time::ptime>, boost::operators_impl::operators_detail::false_t>, boost::operators_impl::operators_detail::empty_base<boost::posix_time::ptime>, boost::operators_impl::operators_detail::true_t>> = {<boost::operators_impl::less_than_comparable1<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::operators_impl::equality_comparable<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::operators_impl::operators_detail::empty_base<boost::posix_time::ptime>, boost::operators_impl::operators_detail::false_t> >> = {<boost::operators_impl::equality_comparable<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::operators_impl::operators_detail::empty_base<boost::posix_time::ptime>, boost::operators_impl::operators_detail::false_t>> = {<boost::operators_impl::equality_comparable1<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::operators_impl::operators_detail::empty_base<boost::posix_time::ptime> >> = {<boost::operators_impl::operators_detail::empty_base<boost::posix_time::ptime>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, time_ = {time_count_ = {
            value_ = 8569444509916594175}}}, <No data fields>}
    desc = {static m_default_line_length = 80, m_caption = "Opties", m_line_length = 80, m_min_description_length = 40,
      m_options = std::vector of length 3, capacity 4 = {{px = 0x6d168, pn = {pi_ = 0x6d980}}, {px = 0x6d188, pn = {pi_ = 0x6f588}}, {px = 0x6f628,
          pn = {pi_ = 0x6f690}}}, belong_to_group = std::vector<bool> of length 3, capacity 32 = {0, 0, 0},
      groups = std::vector of length 0, capacity 0}
    vm = <incomplete type>
#3  0x0003c92c in main (argc=1, argv=0x7efff794) at src/client.cpp:17
    client = {_vptr.Client = 0x57418 <vtable for warmte::Client+8>, vp_Shm = 0x0, vp_Region = 0x0, v_AppName = "warmteclient", l_Index = 0,
      l_Result = 1}
```

Comment: You might be linking to the old library instead of one compiled for the Pi 3.

Comment: I installed the via `sudo apt-get install libboost1.50-all` or the one I use at the moment `sudo apt-get install libboost1.55-all`

Comment: I have tried it with boost 1.64.0 and 1.65.1 both build with C++11 flags (since I use C++ in the application),. Both didn't work. However I am not sure it it is linked to the correct library, how can I verify this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I linked with the wrong libraries....
The installed boost libraries on a Raspberry will end up in /usr/local/lib

So I added `-L/usr/local/lib/` to the linker and changed extend `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with `/usr/local/lib/`. It still remains unclear why this path is not added by default